# Can a data object AND custom error message be returned?

Tags: rest, httpresponse

The following RESTful Service works fine.

Users call the service passing in an Employee number and it returns all the information about the employee.

```
@GET
@Path("/employeeData")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public EmployeeObject getEmployeeInfo(@@QueryParam ("EmployeeNumber") int empNo) 
{

   ////Do Stuff    

    return employeeObject;
 }
```

From what has been read, to return back a custom error message it should look something like the following :

```
@GET
@Path("/employeeData")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public ResponseEntity<Object> getEmployeeInfo(@@QueryParam ("EmployeeNumber") int empNo) 
{

   ////Do Stuff    

   ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), error);
   return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
 }
```

But what if my procedure is more involved and need to return back the object AND an associated error. 
For example :

```
@GET
@Path("/employeeData")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public EmployeeObject getEmployeeInfo(@@QueryParam ("EmployeeNumber") int empNo) 
{

   //DB call to get Employee info works fine. 

   //Based on data in the employee object returned from the 1st call, a 2nd call is
   //is made to the database and that fails.      

    return employeeObject;
 }
```

Even though the 2nd call failed, the user still needs the database from the 1st call but it is also important to know the 2nd call fail instead of the user thinking this employee just didn't have any data.

Is this feasible while at the same time having the Service product json mime type?

The key is to not include the error with the object. Two independent objects should be returned, only if there is an error.

Comment: You can throw an exception and use `ExceptionHandler` to return error object. Checkout this post: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: By throwing the Exception, the Employee data object won't be returned.

Comment: Create `EmployeeResponseDto` and `ErrorDto` classes. The former class will contain `Employee` and `ErrorDto` properties. Add properties in `ErrorDto` class whatever you need related to error. Now you can return `EmployeeResponseDto` in `ResponseEntity`. Also, in case of failure scenario, you can set failure status code (Http Status code 4xx) in ResponseEntity. So that frontend will receive all errors in catch/error block.